# Golang XML marshal two identical attributes

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I'm forced to work with some poorly designed XML, I'm trying to read this XML into a Go structure. Here's some sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>

    <direction from="lojban" to="English">
        <valsi word="cipni" type="gismo">
            <rafsi>cpi</rafsi>
            <definition>x1 is a bird of species x2</definition>
            <notes></notes>
        </valsi>
        ...
    </direction>

    <direction from="English" to="lojban">
        <nlword word="eagle" valsi="atkuila" />
        <nlword word="hawk" sense="bird" valsi="aksiptrina" />
        ...
    </direction>

</dictionary>
```

My issue is I can either read in  nodes or  because they both contain the attribute "word":

```
main.NLWord field "Word" with tag "word,attr" conflicts with field "Valsi" with tag "word,attr"
```

I'm starting to think unmarshalling may be the wrong approach as I'd ideally structure the data differently. Should I read the XML in using some other method and build up data structures manually?

```
type Valsi struct {
    Word  string   `xml:"word,attr"`
    Type  string   `xml:"type,attr"`
    Def   string   `xml:"definition"`
    Notes string   `xml:"notes"`
    Class string   `xml:"selmaho"`
    Rafsi []string `xml:"rafsi"`
}

//Whoever made this XML structure needs to be painfully taught a lesson...
type Collection struct {
    From  string  `xml:"from"`
    To    string  `xml:"to"`
    Valsi []Valsi `xml:"valsi"`
}

type Vlaste struct {
    Direction []Collection `xml:"direction"`
}

var httpc = &http.Client{}

func parseXML(data []byte) Vlaste {
    vlaste := Vlaste{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal(data, &vlaste)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Problem Decoding!")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return vlaste
}
```

Comment: There is no `NLWord` struct in the code fragment you've posted.  Could you update it to include the code that actually caused the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not have grasped what your problem is but the following structure works fine for me
([your modified example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/ZKn_ZmKjPa)):

```
type Valsi struct {
    Word  string   `xml:"word,attr"`
    Type  string   `xml:"type,attr"`
    Def   string   `xml:"definition"`
    Notes string   `xml:"notes"`
    Class string   `xml:"selmaho"`
    Rafsi []string `xml:"rafsi"`
}

type NLWord struct {
    Word  string   `xml:"word,attr"`
    Sense string   `xml:"sense,attr"`
    Valsi string   `xml:"valsi,attr"`
}

type Collection struct {
    From  string    `xml:"from,attr"`
    To    string    `xml:"to,attr"`
    Valsi []Valsi   `xml:"valsi"`
    NLWord []NLWord `xml:"nlword"`
}

type Vlaste struct {
    Direction []Collection `xml:"direction"`
}
```

In this structure, `Collection` can have `Valsi` values as well as `NLWord` values.
You can then decide, depending on `From`/`To` or the length of either `Valsi` or `NLWord` how to handle the data.

Comment: i am new to xml and golang. I have simplified ur code can u tell me difference between [PlayGround1](http://play.golang.org/p/jvvEGkBi8s) and [PlayGround2](http://play.golang.org/p/CTDPwZn49x) i have modified the place of xml tag

Comment: @user2383973 In the second example the xml package does not know to what `Direction` should be mapped to as there is no tag called `Direction`, therefore the tag is needed.